# What is the correct way to reference memory in structs

Tags: rust

I have a struct called *Pizza*. It contains a single *Base* struct and a vector of *Topping* structs.

I have a helper method that returns a *Pizza*. In the (near) future, I see the toppings being a collection somewhere and *Pizza*s being dynamically created from this collection of *Topping*s (mix and match style).

My question is about how the struct should reference Bases and Toppings. If I give ownership to the struct, then it makes it easy to handle it (no lifetime declarations, helper methods are also easier since they no longer need to create the memory outside of scope). However by having *Topping*s outside of scope of my helper method and declaring lifetimes I get less repetition in memory.

How do people reason about these problems? Is there a recommended rule of thumb to follow? Is it possible to have both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Topping` is small (e.g. an `enum`), then you can just copy it (e.g. into `Vec<Topping>`).

If `Topping` is large and you want only one copy in memory, the easiest to work with is to use `Arc<Topping>` which is a shared pointer, and can be cheaply cloned and easily passed around (e.g. into `Vec<Arc<Topping>>`).

If both `Pizza` and `Topping` are used only in a specific statically-known scope (e.g. you create all toppings in `main()` and don't change them later, or you use a memory pool), you may get away with using `&'a Topping` in `Pizza<'a>`, but this is likely to be unnoticeably small performance improvement compared to `Rc`/`Arc`, and keeping track of the temporary lifetime will be annoying.